# Convert command line argument to string

Tags: c++

I have a program that reads hard-coded file-path and I want to make it read file-path from command line instead. For that purpose I changed the code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(char *argv[])
{
...
}
```

but, `argv[1]` variable exposed this way seems to be of type pointer, and I need it as a string. What should I do to convert this command line argument to string?

Comment: The canonical format for `main` is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.  What you have will compile, but it will result in undefined behaviour.

Comment: I don't need arg count, just the string of representing first argument.

Comment: hmm.. `std::string s(argv[1]);` is that what you want to do?

Comment: @theta: It doesn't matter; it still won't work.

Comment: @theta: You can't do that..the signature of `main` has to include `argc` if you intend to use command line arguments.

Comment: The code that prepares the arguments for `main` will still pass argc as the first argument, so skipping it will just lead to "bad things".

Comment: *"It raises error when I use the program on command line."* -- Feel free to be a little more specific.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It's already an array of C-style strings:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) // Don't forget first integral argument 'argc'
{
  std::string current_exec_name = argv[0]; // Name of the current exec program
  std::vector<std::string> all_args;

  if (argc > 1) {
    all_args.assign(argv + 1, argv + argc);
  }
}
```

Argument `argc` is count of arguments plus the current exec file.

Answer (score 35):

You can create an `std::string`

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  // check if there is more than one argument and use the second one
  //  (the first argument is the executable)
  if (argc > 1)
  {
    std::string arg1(argv[1]);
    // do stuff with arg1
  }

  // Or, copy all arguments into a container of strings
  std::vector<std::string> allArgs(argv, argv + argc);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

No need to upvote this. It would have been cool if [Benjamin Lindley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/440119/benjamin-lindley) made his one-liner comment an answer, but since he hasn't, here goes:

`std::vector<std::string> argList(argv, argv + argc);`

If you don't want to include `argv[0]` so you don't need to deal with the executable's location, just increment the pointer by one:

`std::vector<std::string> argList(argv + 1, argv + argc);`

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

std::string commandLineStr= "";
for (int i=1;i<argc;i++) commandLineStr.append(std::string(argv[i]).append(" "));
```

Comment: This would create temporary string objects for no reason at all. `commandLineStr.append(argv[i]).append(" ")` would be much more efficient (`append` returns `*this` to allow this chaining). Also, the default constructor will make the string blank, so the initialization is also wasteful.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is 100% portable but the way the OS **SHOULD** parse the args is to scan through the console command string and insert a nil-term char at the end of each token, and `int main(int,char**)` doesn't use `const char**` so we can just iterate through the args starting from the third argument (**@note** the first arg is the working directory) and scan backward to the nil-term char and turn it into a space rather than start from beginning of the second argument and scanning forward to the nil-term char. Here is the function with test script, and if you do need to un-nil-ify more than one nil-term char then please comment so I can fix it; thanks.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace _ {
/* Converts int main(int,char**) arguments back into a string.
@return false if there are no args to convert.
@param arg_count The number of arguments.
@param args      The arguments. */
bool ArgsToString(int args_count, char** args) {
  if (args_count <= 1) return false;
  if (args_count == 2) return true;
  for (int i = 2; i < args_count; ++i) {
    char* cursor = args[i];
    while (*cursor) --cursor;
    *cursor = ' ';
  }
  return true;
}
}  // namespace _

int main(int args_count, char** args) {
  cout << "\n\nTesting ArgsToString...\n";

  if (args_count <= 1) return 1;
  cout << "\nArguments:\n";
  for (int i = 0; i < args_count; ++i) {
    char* arg = args[i];
    printf("\ni:%i\"%s\" 0x%p", i, arg, arg);
  }
  cout << "\n\nContiguous Args:\n";
  char* end = args[args_count - 1];
  while (*end) ++end;
  cout << "\n\nContiguous Args:\n";
  char* cursor = args[0];
  while (cursor != end) {
    char c = *cursor++;
    if (c == 0)
      cout << '`';
    else if (c < ' ')
      cout << '~';
    else
      cout << c;
  }
  cout << "\n\nPrinting argument string...\n";
  _::ArgsToString(args_count, args);
  cout << "\n" << args[1];
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Just do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::string> argList;
    for(int i=0;i<argc;i++)
        argList.push_back(argv[i]);
    //now you can access argList[n]
}
```

@Benjamin Lindley You are right. This is not a good solution. Please read the one answered by juanchopanza.

Comment: Skip the loop and just use the vector constructor. `std::vector<std::string> argList(argv, argv + argc);`

Comment: That's a lot of overhead to extract one string.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley can you explain what that means? For example, if I didn't want to include `argv[0]`, what would I change in that line? I think this is the kind of initializer being used, but I can't be certain: `initializer_list<value_type> il,
       const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type()` : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/

Comment: Well, my co-worker hooked me up with an answer to my specific request, at least :) `std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv + argc);` I didn't realize the first parameter was just a pointer, ergo a single increment would be all that's needed.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley can you explain how this code works ?

Answer (score 1):

Because all attempts to print the argument I placed in my variable failed, here my 2 bytes for this question:

```
std::string dump_name;

(stuff..)

if(argc>2)
{
    dump_name.assign(argv[2]);
    fprintf(stdout, "ARGUMENT %s", dump_name.c_str());
}
```

Note the use of assign, and also the need for the c_str() function call.