# Fail compile when include String

Tags: c++, string

Here is a simple C++ program and I believe it should work. My code is reference from here.
[Convert command line argument to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344714/convert-command-line-argument-to-string)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector> 
#include <iostream>


//using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

std::string boss;
//printf("PROGRAM NAME: %s\n", argv[0]);


if (argc > 1){
    //printf("%s\n",&argv[1][0]);
    printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    boss = argv[1];
}

}
```

When Compile it come out the problem:

/tmp/cctYLBpB.o: In function `main':
testarg.cpp:(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to`std::basic_string, std::allocator >::basic_string()'
testarg.cpp:(.text+0x58): undefined reference to `std::string::operator=(char const*)'
testarg.cpp:(.text+0x64): undefined reference to`std::basic_string, std::allocator >::~basic_string()'
testarg.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
testarg.cpp:(.text+0x7c): undefined reference to`__cxa_end_cleanup'
/tmp/cctYLBpB.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
testarg.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to`std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
testarg.cpp:(.text+0xe4): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/cctYLBpB.o:(.ARM.extab+0x0): undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Did you guys expert had seen any problem on it ? I have no idea ...

Comment: What command(s) did you use to build your program?

Comment: the command(s) i use to compile is gcc "filename".cpp -o testc

Comment: Use `g++` to compile/build.

Comment: wow ! g++ is work , i accidentally forgot gcc is for c program, g++ is for c++ program ! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `gcc` to build your program, the standard C++ libraries are not used by the linker. Use `g++` instead. Add `-Wall` for good measure. You will get useful warning messages that will help you find problems at compile time rather than find them at run time.

```
g++ filename.cpp -Wall -o testc
```