# How to use parameter in exe

Tags: exe

I want to use parameters in a program I made in C/C++ languages. Example:

```
MaxPayne2.exe -developer -developerkeys
```

I want to use a parameter like this in my exe file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

While I would usually recommend adding more context this is your answer.

The standard c++ main has two additional parameters,

`int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {  }`

To use these "arguments" (as they are called) you just reference their point in the argv array.

argc = the number of additional arguments supplied.

argv = the array of argument values supplied.

Example:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
 cout << argv[argc-1]; //Prints out the last argument supplied.
}
```

(note)If my syntax is wrong someone please correct me, my c++ is a bit rusty.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for, but I want to capture all parameters, just like the example above.

Comment: That does capture all parameters.

Comment: It captures them in an array

Comment: @9AspecT If this answered your question please mark my answer as correct so this question can be closed

Comment: Here is another reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15344714/convert-command-line-argument-to-string