# searching length of sting in arg[]

Tags: c++, argv, argc

I'm trying to get string length from char argv array but I don't know how to check this.

I'm writing 3 words to console for example: red blue yellow.
Then I want to write out "yellow" but I don't know how to do that.
I tried to save the words in a file but I don't have backspaces in the file this looks that:
redblueyellow

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std; 
int main(int argc,char* argv[]) { 
    string temp; 
    fstream save; 
    string tab[argc]; 
    for(int i=1; i<argc; i++) { 
        if(argv[i]==' ') { 
            tab[argv]=tab[i]; 
        }
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
string tab[argc];
```

is not valid ISO C++, because the length of the array must be a compile-time constant. Some compilers may support [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) as an extension, though.

However, it is possible to convert the C-style `argv` strings to a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). See this question for further information:

[Convert command line argument to string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15344714/12149471)

In your code, the line

```
if(argv[i]==' ') {
```

does not make sense, as you are comparing a pointer to a string with a character literal.

---

If you call your program like this

```
myprogramname red blue yellow
```

then the following will apply:

- `argc` will have the value `4`
- `argv[0]` will point to a string containing `myprogramname`
- `argv[1]` will point to a string containing `red`
- `argv[2]` will point to a string containing `blue`
- `argv[3]` will point to a string containing `yellow`
- `argv[4]` will have the value `NULL`

Therefore, if you want to print `yellow`, you can simply write

```
std::cout << argv[3] << '\n';
```

If you want to print the length of the string `yellow`, you can simply write

```
std::cout << std::strlen( argv[3] ) << '\n';
```

Note that you must `#include <cstring>` in order to use [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen).

Alternatively, instead of using `std::strlen`, you can first convert `argv[3]` to a [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), before obtaining its length:

```
std::string str{ argv[3] };
std::cout << str.length() << '\n';
```

If you want to write to a file, such as to the [`std::fstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream) with the name `save` in your program, then you can replace `std::cout` with `save` in the code above. However, you will have to open the file first, before using it. Also, you may want to consider using [`std::ofstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream) instead of `std::fstream`, because you seem to only want to use the file for writing, not reading.

Comment: thanks u, but how get longest word from this array? for example I want to print yellow but I don't know how I tried use argv[I].length() and argv[I].size()

Comment: @BartekSacha: Calling `length()` or `size()` will not work on a C-style string (i.e. a null-terminated character array). It will only work on C++ strings (i.e. [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)). Therefore, if you want to use these functions, you will first have to convert the individual C-style strings to `std::string`. In two places of my answer, I showed you how to do that. Alternatively, you can use [`std::strlen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) on a C-style string. I also showed you how to do that in my answer.